# I have request data from 2 database. How can I merge code to one function?

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs, node.js, express

I have request data from 2 database. But I need to merge 2 request in one function and send data to result.html

```
function showResult(req, res){
        var n = req.query.query
        mysql_conn.query('SELECT query_text FROM catalogsearch_query WHERE query_text LIKE "%' + n + '%" ORDER BY popularity DESC LIMIT 0 , 10', function(error, rows) {
        res.render('result.html',{result:n , related: rows.map(row => row.query_text)})
    })
}
```

Need to merge with this code

```
mysql_crawl.query('SELECT prod_name, full_price, discount_price, quantity, prod_link, images, prod_desc, status FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` WHERE MATCH(data_index) AGAINST("cream") LIMIT 0 , 10', function(error, product_data){
res.render('result.html',{product_data: product_data})
```

How can I merge code together in one function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is asynchronous, we have to wait for till we have both responses to execute the `render`. (If the `mysql` module supports promises, you can do it [another way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).).

```
var n = req.query.query;
mysql_conn.query('SELECT query_text FROM catalogsearch_query WHERE query_text LIKE "%' + n + '%" ORDER BY popularity DESC LIMIT 0 , 10', function (error, rows) {

    // at this point, only the first query has been executed

    mysql_crawl.query('SELECT prod_name, full_price, discount_price, quantity, prod_link, images, prod_desc, status FROM `catalogsearch_fulltext` WHERE MATCH(data_index) AGAINST("cream") LIMIT 0 , 10', function(error, product_data) {

        // at this point, both queries should have been executed

        res.render('result.html', {
           result: n, 
           related: rows.map(row => row.query_text),
           product_data: product_data
        })
    });
});
```

I never used this module, but be careful of SQL injection.